# Reason for precedence of instanceof/is

Tags: c#, java, language-theory

In both C#/Java the operator precedence of `is` respectively `instanceof` leads to some ugly necessary parenthesis. For example instead of writing `if (!bar instanceof Foo)` you have to write `if (!(bar instanceof Foo))`.

So why did the language teams decide that `!` has a higher operator precedence than is/instanceof? Admittedly in C# you can overwrite `operator!` which would lead to a different result in some situations, but those situations seems exceedingly rare (and non-intuitive in any case), while the case of checking if something is not a type or subtype of something is much more likely.

Comment: Shouldn't this be over on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Adrian Imo it's better fitted here and I don't see anything about language-theory in programmers' description.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conspiracy theory:

C# designers **don't want you to use `is` operator**. Usage of this operator is often a smell of bad OOP design. If you find yourself using it often, it probably means that your class hierarchy is wrong and you need to rely on virtual methods and patterns more heavily. Java designers went even further: they named the operator `instanceof` to make you cringe every time you use it.

This isn't unlikely actually. There're many cases when language and library designers make some features inconvenient to use. Some examples: character encodings in .NET (you should always use Unicode), `goto` in Pascal (you should avoid it) etc. Sometimes it is caused by bad design (like WPF in .NET), but sometimes it's intentional.

Comment: This one is actually a really good reason and I agree that it's not far-fetched. Both Java and C# go out of their way to push programmers towards a specific programming style and avoidance of this operator certainly fits in there.

Answer (score 16):

In Java, `instanceof` is one of the [relational operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20) and has the same precedence as the other ones:

```
RelationalExpression:
    ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpression < ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpression > ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpression <= ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpression >= ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpression instanceof ReferenceType
```

From that perspective it makes sense that those two lines should follow the same structure:

```
if (!(a instanceof b))
if (!(a < b))
```

Comment: Sure but that's only the technical reason, i.e. how it's implemented (and I actually find it quite strange that you'd throw instance of into the relational operators), but not why they put it in there.

Comment: RelationExpression is the only category that makes sense for instanceof (IMO). One alternative would have been to create a specific category.

Answer (score 11):

Here are my thoughts on the matter with no authoritative source.

`instanceof` is a very large operator. Most operators are two characters at most. Additionally, `instanceof` must have whitespace between it and a variable. Because of these two unique things, when you look at an expression like `!bar instanceof Foo`, the `instanceof` seems to naturally separate `!bar` and `Foo`, and many people would find it surprising if `!bar` was not a sub-expression.

Similar lines of thought can also be applied to `is`, with the additional argument of just following what Java already did.

Answer (score 3):

I think it’s just historical. If I remember correctly in the very first versions of Java you could not even write `if(a instanceof Foo || a instanceof Bar)` without parentheses. I think there was a change around Java 2. I don’t know why they didn’t put it on a higher precedence (e.g. higher than logical not). Maybe because it would interfere with the typecast operator and thus break compatibility then?

C# seems to have just used the same precedence as Java then.

I still think that it is a mistake as well to keep the precedence of bitwise and/or on the same level as the logical and/or. Having to write things like `if( (x&(FLAG1|FLAG2)) != 0) …` is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

`instanceof` is a binary operator.
`!` is a unary operator.

It would be *very confusing* for `instanceof` to bind more tightly than `!`.
A classic example of the confusion is `**` and `-` in Python, where we have:

```
-1 ** 2 == -(1 ** 2)  # true
```

I don't know about you, but this just looks ridiculous to me in Python, so I'm glad they're not doing the same thing in Java.

Another Python example is:

```
False is (not None)   # false
```

and

```
False is not None     # true
```

which I think is equally confusing, this time because `is` and `is not` are different operators.

Answer (score 1):

Because by writing `if (!bar instanceof Foo)` it negates the bar and then looks for instanceof. because this it the most left statement and I dont think that instanceof even has precedence

then `if (!(bar instanceof Foo))` it makes it instanceof first and then negates the whole thing.

if you need to negate bar and then check for instance then do `((!bar) instanceof Foo)`

Comment: Yes I understand the basics of how operator precedence works. The question is why the operator precedence was chosen in such a way. Clearly you don't have to write `5 + (2 * 3)` to get the correct result of 11 instead of 21 - exactly because the operator precedence was correctly chosen ("correctly" obviously only applicable for the specific domain of integers). Same could be done here - or not? That's the question.

Comment: What does it mean to negate an Object?

Comment: Negating an object would only work if it had an implicitly castable boolean value, I would have thought.

Comment: yeah I also noticed but I guess author was more interested in the technical staff than actual logic

Comment: Also I would repeat myself again, presence is something belongs to the mathematical operators. instanceof doesn't have one so it comes whenever interpreter reaches it

Comment: @Jeff `operator!` can be arbitrarily overloaded in C#, but yes that's the main point - hardly ever useful so why chose such an order. The claim that precedence belongs to mathematical operators is wrong, *all* operators have to be defined and `instanceof` is no exception. Same for casts, object access (`.`) or array member accesses - all clearly defined precedence in the language spec. Left associativity only applies on the same level of precedence and even then only if it's stated! The assignment precedence level is defined as right associative for example.

Answer (score 1):

1. `instanceof` is very long word comparing to basic operators like `+` or `++`. When you read condition, you just lost your focus, at least I do.
2. It's surrounded by spaces which can increase readability but on the other hand you are unable to *connect it* with other operands, e.g. like `5+6` can do.

I believe that guys decided to say: *ok, lower priority so everyone must provide parenthesis to be sure what's going on*

Answer (score 1):

Obiously, an expression like `!b instanceof SomeType` (read: "negate `b`, then check if the resulting value is of Type `SomeType`") doesn't make much sense in Java:

Logically, `b` had to be some kind of boolean object (so that `!` works) and even if you negated its value, it would still be a boolean value, of the same type as before, so why bother negating it in the first place?

(Actually, you can't even do it: `b` can't be a `boolean`, because `instanceof` requires it to be a real `Object`, but then again, if `b` is a `Boolean`, `!b` would still evaluate to a primitive `boolean`, so `instanceof` doesn't work.)

We can therefore say that `!b instanceof SomeType` has no semantic meaning in Java at all. So we could reassign its meaning to "check if `b` is not of type `SomeType`" - can't we?

Given that this could've been changed semantically and still wasn't done leaves me with the conclusion that this was not really intentional, but there was a more pragmatic reason to go with the lower precedence for `instanceof`:

Off the top of my head, I would suspect that parsing gets complicated if you give `instanceof` higher precedence than the unary operator `!`. You might want to check that.

On the other hand, if `!b instanceof SomeType` would mean "check if `b` is not of type `SomeType`", this could still trick novice programmers into thinking that `!` operates on `b` when in fact it negates the result of `instanceof`, so it's  less ambiguous to leave `!b instanceof SomeType` essentially undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Because the C programming language got it wrong, and Java blindly followed C.

In C, ! and ~ are the same precedence.  It does not actually matter much in C in practice because one writes 
    a<b 
rather than 
    !(a>=b).

But there is no notinstanceof operator.

You might also ask why /* /* */ */ do not nest properly.  Or why Java counts from 0.  Or why there needs to be a void keyword.  Or why Java uses the horrid {{}{}} notation instead of endif (or fi).  It's all C legacy.

And perhaps for good reason.  C programmers will argue that all these things are the correct approach, because it is what they are used to.  And Java's first job was to become noticed and used, unlike many other little long forgotten programming languages.

Be grateful that Java does not have null terminated strings.